# How to pass in different function pointers into atexit in c?

Tags: c, exit, atexit

I understand that `atexit()` takes in a function pointer of this type `void (*function)(void)`. What I want to do is that whenever the porgam exists it runs a function to free of all the memory. So I want `atexit()` to take in this function pointer instead
`void (*function)(struct Node)`. Is there a way around this, or something similar that will allow me to do this.

Comment: When `exit()` is calling the function, how would it know what to pass as the `struct Node` argument?

Comment: the callback functions can't take arguments. If they need to process any data, it must be global variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add your own register for cleanup functions:

```
typedef void atexit_f(void*);
void my_atexit(atexit_f* callback, void *data);
```

The register would be kept in a global variable (i.e. linked list).
The register would be cleaned up in a cleanup function registered with `atexit()`.

```
struct cleanup_node {
   atexit_f *cb;
   void *data;
   struct cleanup_node *next;
};

static struct cleanup_node *head;

void my_atexit_cleanup(void) {
  for (struct cleanup_node *node = head; node; node = node->next) {
     node->cb(node->data);
  }
  // free nodes itself
}

...

int main() {
  atexit(my_atexit_cleanup);
  ...
  my_atexit(some_function, some_data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you pass to `atexit` *must* have a matching function signature.

If this function's job is to free some memory, the pointer to that memory must be made available as a file-scope variable.